# Change format of datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want format like

```
17-April-2011 9:05 PM
```

How to do this in sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `CONVERT(varchar(50), datecol, 130)` - [format 130 seems closest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and replace some spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Use the CONVERT or CAST function (see documentation) which offer a number of formats. But be careful with what you do with it. This is fine for displaying, but could result in inefficient queries if you use the result in a query expression.

And if you are using it for display, you will probably have better formatting options in the language you are using at the UI level.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get from the built-in `CONVERT` function is `17 Apr 2011 9:05:00:000PM`:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 130)
```

See also:

- [*How to format datetime & date in Sql Server 2005*](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) by Anubhav Goyal
- [*CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

113 is also similar:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 113)
```